# How to encourage or triggers others to help me when everyone seems busy with their task

Tags: work-environment, team, helping

I have joined as a team lead in a new company but yet no reportees are assigned to me . In this company timelines and accuracy of response to client are very important as compare to my previous organizations as client is technical and very strict.

Work pressure is high in my current project and team members normally work for 12-14 hours to complete their daily task. Now, as I am new to this project I need help from others to get my work done but as I said team members are too busy with their work that they normally execuse me by saying that they also don't know about that and you need to find out it by your own or they give very short answer for my questions  which don't lead to any understanding for me and becomes really difficult for me to how to ask next questions again for more clarification. With this my personality is that I found it difficult to ask questions to other and their such behavior are creating worst situation for me.

As I have IT experience of more than 8+ years my project manager is expecting me to deal this situation by my own and expect from me that I should know how to get help from others.

Kindly help me to deal with this situation as I want to know how to improve my way of asking question that will lead others to answer my question even in their busy schedule or is there any specific way of asking questions to others which triggers others to help me

Comment: Hey kulwal, this seems to be very similar to your [last question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16798/team-members-coming-late-to-meeting-organized-by-me) about people coming to meetings late in that they both seem to be about the same problem: *"how do I get people to lend me their time and support?"* Is there any reason the other question's answers didn't satisfy you? Or is there something very different about this question? If possible, could you [edit] with any information that would distinguish them?

Comment: @@Jmac: I normally don't do meetings and it is only during special time when we need to send some information or ask from or some specific details from client, but this question is related to my every day or you can say my every hour of task i.e. how to encourage team mates to help me

Comment: From 5 years I was working in same company and as I was well known with work of that company I don't face any such issue

Answer (score 4):

> As I have IT experience of more than 8+ years my project manager is
>   expecting me to deal this situation by my own and expect from me that
>   I should know how to get help from others.
>
> Kindly help me to deal with this situation

Based on your question and comments, it sounds like your 8 years of experience didn't give you the background on dealing with these situations that your project manager expected. That happens.

As a manager, whenever I assign a task to someone, and they don't know how to accomplish the expected results, I want them to come to me, talk about it, and we can work out a plan together for dealing with it. That doesn't mean I do the work for them, or even that I provide extra help, but it often means that we jointly propose how to get bast the roadblock.

From the outside, it's not going to possible for one of us to determine *why* you aren't able to get the help you need. We aren't close enough to your situation to suggest anything other than wide generalities that may or may not apply ("be more assertive", "complain to the boss", etc). To solve your specific problems, you must discuss this with your boss and/or project manager.

Go speak with your boss/project manager, since they alone are in a position to give you what you need. Tell them that you don't have any experience dealing with this sort of situation. Ask for their advice - then follow it.